# Simple Java to XML example

Tags: java, xml

I've read a time ago about generate xml from Java using annotations, but I'm not finding a simple example now.

If I want to make a xml file like:

```
<x:element uid="asdf">value</x:element>
```

from my java class:

```
public class Element {
  private String uid = "asdf";
  private String value = "value";
}
```

Which annotations should I use to perform that? (I have a xml-schema, if this helps the generation)

**--update**

The [javax.xml.bind.annotation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html) package have the annotations, "but I still haven't found what I'm looking for": an exemple of usage.. :)

Comment: JAXB is better for most work but Simple works on Android: http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class JavaToXMLDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);

    Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    Employee object = new Employee();
    object.setCode("CA");
    object.setName("Cath");
    object.setSalary(300);

    m.marshal(object, System.out);

  }
}

@XmlRootElement
class Employee {
  private String code;

  private String name;

  private int salary;

  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
  }

  public void setSalary(int population) {
    this.salary = population;
  }
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employee>
    <code>CA</code>
    <name>Cath</name>
    <salary>300</salary>
</employee>
```

From: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.xml.bind.annotation/javaxxmlbindannotationXmlRootElement.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are various tools that you can use to do this.  XStream (http://x-stream.github.io/) is a reasonably easy tool to use that allows you to use annotations to determine the schema of XML that is created.

Comment: I would like JDK included tools

Comment: You'll have to go outside the JDK, What you are looking for is a tool that customizes serialization--I think that's what XStream does.  Instead of serialization going to a binary unreadable mess it goes to XML.  Of course that might not give you exactly what you are looking for, but it's the closest thing i can think of.

Comment: @Brito: yes, JAXB does exactly that. XStream is not strictly necessary (it's a third-party library that existed before JAXB, if I remember correctly).

Comment: @Joachim - JAXB was created first.

Comment: @Blaise: interesting, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone else hitting this thread, I imagine you did the following:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Element { 

  @XmlAttribute
  private String uid = "asdf"; 

  @XmlValue
  private String value = "value"; 
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html